# Simulink - Update struct parameter from initialization callback

Tags: matlab, simulink

I created a Simulink library block for a DC motor with a 'Mask' to setup the motor parameter. The mechanic part is implemented with Simscape within a subblock. The subblock also has a mask with one parameter for a structure storing the (complex) simscape configuration. This parameter is promoted to the parent mask. The Simscape configuration data struct lives in the base workspace. This approach works.

Now I tried to extend the library block for specific motor models (e.g. modelA,modelB,...). Therefore I
implemented within the 'block initialization callback' a switch/case. One case for each model. Within the case statement the specific data is load from a *.mat file and the block parameters are updated like:

```
cfg = load( 'modelA' );
set_param( blk, 'elec_R', num2str( cfg.elec.R ) );
set_param( blk, 'elec_L', num2str( cfg.elec.L ) );
```

The Simscape parameter struct is also part of the loaded config. A simple approach like:

```
set_param( blk, 'mech_sims', 'cfg.sims' );
```

fails because 'cfg' is not part of the base workspace and therefore missing during model evaluation. So my question is how can I setup my subblock with structure data which is only available within my callback function context ? Is it possible to force the evaluation from the callback function context e.g.:

```
Simulink.Evaluate( 'myDCMotorBlk' )
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I found a solution. I store the simscape struct within the blocks user data:

```
set_param( blk, 'UserData', cfg.sims );
```

The mech_smi parameter is set as follows:

```
set_param( blk, 'mech_smi', [ 'get_param(''' blk ''',''UserData'')' ] );
```

Therefore during evaluation the required data is loaded from block specific user data parameter.